# Azure DevOps - how to know a Resolved work item is actively being tested (vs. in the queue)

Tags: azure-devops

## TLDR;

Does Azure DevOps have a recommended built in way of marking Resolved Work Items as being actively tested as opposed of being in the queue for testing?

## Details

My team is using Azure DevOps with Agile workflow.

This means that out-of-the box a user story goes through the following states

1. **New** -> Implementation started ->
2. **Active** -> Code complete ->
3. **Resolved** -> Acceptance tests passed ->
4. **Closed**

This is nicely shown at [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/guidance/choose-process?view=azure-devops):

[image: user story states]

Testing happens in when the story (or bug) is in the Resolved state.

The out of the box board has 4 lanes.
[image]

When looking at the board (or even in queries) I'm having trouble seeing what is being actively tested.

For example, if there are 2 resolved items it is not clear which one is being actively worked on and which one is waiting to be picked up.

Showing what is being tested seems like a common desire and my intuition is that the solution for my problem is built in. I want to avoid customising the workflow (and adding a new state called Testing).

*Cross-post from [pm.stackexchange.com](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/26434/azure-devops-how-to-know-a-resolved-work-item-is-actviely-being-tested-vs-in)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest using the [Kanban board](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/boards/kanban-basics?view=azure-devops) and adding a column named Testing. This won't require adding a custom state to your workflow but does give you more visibility into the state of a work item.

You can also [split columns into Doing and Done](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/boards/split-columns?view=azure-devops) so you know where an item is stuck in the flow of your work.

Answer (score 1):

In my company we have been in the same situation.
I like @Wouter's answer and I think it deserves upvotes, but I just want to expose it in another way (it depends on your needs, maybe they are similar to mine).

In my company we have a board with a column called "Testing" (divided into "Doing" and "Done") but this board is only for developers, for their tests. But in our development lifecycle there is another step called "UAT" where the software is deployed in a test environment called "uat" ... and is tested by business users who run their own acceptance tests.
Now, we developers don't want these business users to use Azure DevOps Boards or, worse, change work item states (we tried, it can be a mess).
We want to isolate their actions on a Test Plan.
Therefore, when the release pipeline deploys in the "uat" stage N work items, it also creates a Test Plan with N test cases (manual, not automated) that our business users must validate with Pass / No pass.
When all test cases have been validated, we can deploy the build to Production.
Maybe this suites you.

Comment: "we tried, it can be a mess" :)